# Is it possible to put refs in an array?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to be able to get the `measure()` of all the refs I assigned. This is what I am trying to manage:

```
 <View
    ref="dropZone[]">
 </View>
 <View
    ref="dropZone[]">
 </View>

 lets dropZones = []
 for(let i=0; i < refs.length; i++){
    this.refs[i].measure((ox, oy, width, height, px, py) => {
      dropZones.push({x: px, y:py, height: height, width: width})
    }
 }
```

What would be the best way to manage this?

Comment: Does it work? If it works - it is "the best" otherwise it's not.

Comment: I was just trying to show an example this way. Is it even possible to declare an array in a prop?

Comment: It is possible - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Answer (score 0):

Using arrow functions I managed to do it this way in the `render()`:

```
 <View
    ref={c => this.dropZones.set(0, c)}>
 </View>
 <View
    ref={c => this.dropZones.set(1, c)}>
 </View>
```

And I used this in `componentDidMount()`:

```
 Array.from(this.dropZones.values())
   .forEach(dropZone => {
     dropZone.measure((ox, oy, width, height, px, py) => {
       dropZonesArray.push({x: px, y:py, height: height, width: width})
    })
 })
```